# How to insert into SQL table with previous data check

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm creating a table in which I will store bookmakers odds changes for sport events over time (it will have hundrets k of rows).
I want to create an update function in PHP, which puts in the table data only if current_odd_value is different than most recent odd_value stored in table.

Using simple INSERT function I created this table of 1 match (8483075) from two companies (66 and 22) for the same market (1) which has 3 selection (1001, 1002, 1003) that I get today at 17:00:

| internal_id | match_id | company_id | market_id | selection_id | odd_value | update_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8483075 | 66 | 1 | 1001 | 9,60 | 2021-01-04 17:00:00 |
| 2 | 8483075 | 66 | 1 | 1002 | 18,00 | 2021-01-04 17:00:00 |
| 3 | 8483075 | 66 | 1 | 1003 | 1,09 | 2021-01-04 17:00:00 |
| 4 | 8483075 | 22 | 1 | 1001 | 8,40 | 2021-01-04 17:00:00 |
| 5 | 8483075 | 22 | 1 | 1002 | 16,00 | 2021-01-04 17:00:00 |
| 6 | 8483075 | 22 | 1 | 1003 | 1,08 | 2021-01-04 17:00:00 |

At 17:05 I checked odds once again and I noticed 2 changes (for internal_id 2 and 6):

- 2 / 8483075 / 66 / 1 / 1002 / 15,00 ==> 18,00
- 6 / 8483075 / 22 / 1 / 1003 / 1,08 ==> 1,18

, that I should put into that table and should look like this:

| internal_id | match_id | company_id | market_id | selection_id | odd_value | update_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 8483075 | 66 | 1 | 1002 | 15,00 | 2021-01-04 17:05:00 |
| 8 | 8483075 | 22 | 1 | 1003 | 1,18 | 2021-01-04 17:05:00 |

My idea to do that was to:

1. get table of all recent odd values for each match_id + company_id + market_id + selection_id
2. compare it with current odd value and only if it's different than value from point 1. put new record into table with proper data

MY QUESTIONS:

1. What will be the SELECT query to get what I need for point 1? I think I can use internal_id (higher means most recent) or update_date to get it, but I don't know how. I know how to make it for specific match_id + company_id + makret_id + selection_id but I need whole table in one select not one by one.
2. Is my approach correct or I should try different approach? (I think that retriving whole table at the beginning of update with most recent odds should be faster than comparing each value one by one)

Additional info:

1. All data that I have are coming from XML/JSON files that I'm receiving from different sources (so different formats etc. that I'm unifying under my db).

Comment: Please tag your question with database that you are using. Amd also let us know wherw the current data comes from. Is it stored in some table or in some variable. You will need current data to compare with old ones.

Comment: Added tag + Additional Info directly in the question